# How to pass a dictionary parameters with '&' to Objective-C method in Swift

Tags: swift, objective-c, swift5

I have a Objective-C library (and my project is Swift source).
I'm trying to use the library's methods.

there's a method like below

```
- (int)recognize:(NSDictionary **)dictionaryResult;
```

In ObjC, simply call it like

```
NSDictionary *resultDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
nRet = [crControl recognize:&resultDictionary];
```

However in Swift, when I call the method like below, an error occurs

```
var dictionary = NSDictionary.init()
nRet = crControl.recognize(&dictionary)
```

==================

The error message:

> Cannot convert value of type 'AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer' to expected argument type 'AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSDictionary?>'

How can I pass a empty dictionary with '&' to ObjC methods in Swift?

Comment: I think `NSDictionary *resultDictionary;` will be enough, don't need to init it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The translation to swift seems to have translated the parameter type to:

```
AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSDictionary?>
```

Note that it's a pointer to an *optional* `NSDictionary`, so you should declare the argument as an optional too:

```
var dictionary: NSDictionary? = .init()
```

Comment: I think `var dictionary: NSDictionary? = nil` will be enough, don't need to init it.

Comment: @Cy-4AH The Objective-C code in the question _did_ init it, and I don't know whether `recognize` will work with `NULL`s.

Comment: @Sweeper yes of course, we don't know exact implementation of `recognize` method. My comment was more for question author.